# how can i get out numbers from a variable which contains a string? -power shell

Tags: powershell

So I have got a file which contains lines like this :

```
Peter Nagy 3 4 6 7 4
```

I need a Power shell script which asks the user to give a name, and it maths out the avarage of thoose numbers next to that name. Please help :)

```
$name1 = read-host 
$content = Get-Content test.txt
$talalt = $content | Where-Object { $_ -match  $name1 }
```

I have no idea what to do after this, and how to get out of thoose numbers from that string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to select from the first digit to the end of the line, split out the individual numbers and then average them e.g.:

```
$content | Where-Object { $_ -match  $name1 } | 
   Foreach {if ($_ -match '\D+(\d.*)') {-split $matches[1] | measure -average }}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you need:

```
$name1 = read-host 
$content = Get-Content NamesList.txt
$talalt = $content | Where-Object { $_ -match  $name1 }

$SplitString = $talalt.split(" ")

$NumberofNumbers = $SplitString.count-2

$total = 0;

for($i=2;$i-le $SplitString.count;$i++)
{
    $total = [int]$SplitString[$i] + $total
}

$average = $total/$NumberofNumbers

write-host "Average for $($name1) is $($average)"
```

regards
Arcass

Comment: If you use string.split(" "), you'll probably want to use the `[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries` otherwise any additional space between individual numbers will generate empty entries in your $SplitString array.  Or you could just use `-split $talalt` and it will remove emptry entries for you.